# Search optimal parameters on predictions for a trained machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization

I have created a ML model from the following electric circuit

[image]

As the imput I'm only using the values of R3 and R5 which I'm changing an the ranges:

R3: 1 to 5
R5: 10 to 150 in steps of 10

My target value is the efficiency of the circuit measured as the power consumed by R5 vs the power delivered by V1

Once I trained the model, I made the prediction for a larger range of values and got this surface that has the efficiency on the Z axis:

[image]

My question is,  given a set e.g:

X1= 1
X2= 3

Which leads to an output predicted efficiency of 50%

How can I automate the process of recommend a better value, e.g:

X1= 1
X2= 1

which produces an efficiency of 57%

I would like to do this subject to some constrains like: only move 2 steps on X1 and 3 steps on X2

Comment: This question is lacking a lot of relevant information. Which ML model are you using? Which obective function? Is the procedure you described used only to generate a training set? 

In case it helps, it looks to me like a scenario where an analytic solution will probably be simpler and easier to implement than a ML model.

Comment: @torresmateo The ML model in particular is not relevant, the solution should work with any other algorithm. Yes, the process I described is only to generate the training set. Whether  an ML model is or isn't the best fit to solve the problem isn't the question either.

Comment: I understand. Regarding the restriction on the search space, by "step" do you mean that the search space is discrete? Is a function for any arbitrary pair (x1, x2) available for the search algorithm?

Comment: @torresmateo right, the function is continuous, but the variables have physical restrictions e.g.  hence the search space it is discrete

Comment: I would throw simulated annealing at is (if function can be calculated fairly fast), let me know if you need a working minimum example

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the job for an optimizer such as gradient descent (recommended if you can implement your ML model in a framework with automatic differentiation such as PyTorch or TensorFlow).

If a gradient based optimizer is not suitable for your particular function, I'd suggest [Evolutionary Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm). Based on the description in your question, I'd suggest the following options:

- a genetic algorithm, such as [NSGA-II](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/996017) Python implementation: https://jmetal.github.io/jMetalPy/api/algorithm/multiobjective/eas/nsgaii.html
- [Ant Colony Optimization Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) Python implementation: https://pypi.org/project/ACO-Pants/
- [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) Python implementation: https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

All of these algorithms are suitable for discrete search spaces, and in case they don't offer a convenient API for constraining the search space, you can get around that issue by wrapping your model:

Let your ML model be a function:

```py
f(x1: float, x2:float) -> float
```

you can write a wrapper function `f_constrained` as follows:

```py
def f_constrained(x1: float, x1: float, 
                  x1_min: float, x1_max: float, 
                  x2_min: float, x2_max: float) -> float:
    if x1_min <= x1 <= x1_max and x2_min <= x2 <= x2_max:
        return f(x1, x2)
    # this assumes the objective function is maximizing the values,
    # when minimizing, return float("inf") instead
    return float("-inf")
```